# wso2 identity server - disabling user sign up

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I would like to disable the default wso2 identity server functionality that allows new users to sign themselves up ([wso2is user guide description](http://wso2.org/project/solutions/identity/3.2.3/docs/userguide.html#t1)).

Instead, I would only like the administrator to be able to create new users.  Is this possible?  How do I configure this?

Comment: I can't see the option to disable users signing themselves up.  Is this on the roadmap?

Comment: If this functionality doesn't exist and it isn't on the roadmap - roughly how much effort would it be required to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to disable users from registering themselves on the WSO2 identity server.

The steps to follow for disabling users from self registering can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429196/wso2-identity-server-user-self-registration)