# wso2 identity server - user self registration

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm rewording a question that I previously posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317440/wso2-identity-server-disabling-user-sign-up).

The default functionality for WSO2 Identity Server is to allow users to register user accounts for themselves.  However, this is undesirable for my company.   We only want to allow an administrator to create user accounts.

Is it possible to disable the user self registration functionality in wso2 identity server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can remove this feature from the WSO2 Identity Server.

Go to Configure --> Features --> Installed Features --> Identity Self Registration --> Uninstall --> Restart the server.