# wso2 identity server - re-add self-registration after removing it

Tags: configuration, wso2, wso2-identity-server

While setting up a new WSO2 Identity Server 4.1.0 I was asked to disable the self-registration. I followed the steps in [wso2 identity server - user self registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429196/wso2-identity-server-user-self-registration) which worked fine. I'm now needing to add self-registration back into the system though.

I added the following feature repository: http://dist.wso2.org/p2/carbon/releases/4.0.3 (which seems to be the correct one) and tried adding the 'Identity Self Registration Feature' v4.0.3 (the version that was removed) back into the system. I get presented with a dialogue stating that 'Following license(s) must be reviewed and accepted before installing features.' with no licenses listed. When I press Next it doesn't do anything. Back & Cancel both work fine but I can't proceed further.

I have even tried shutting down the system and copying the features back in from the zip distribution and starting it back up. This does not seem to re-register them with the system.

The features copied back in from the zip are everything under the following locations:

```
repository/components/features/org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration_4.0.3
repository/components/features/org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration.server_4.0.1
repository/components/features/org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration.ui_4.0.3
```

Any help on getting this turned back on would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Still not certain on why the license acceptance dialogue isn't showing that may be a bug. In any case I've managed to get the feature added back in. For those trying to do this after me here's the steps involved.

1. Stop the service
2. take a backup (just to be safe)
3. copy from a fresh unzip the following structures into the corresponding locations in your installation

   - repository/components/features/org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration_4.0.3
   - repository/components/features/org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration.server_4.0.1
   - repository/components/features/org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration.ui_4.0.3
4. Increase the artifacts size count by 3 in repository/components/artifacts.xml and add the following content to it

   ```
   <artifact classifier='org.eclipse.update.feature' id='org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration' version='4.0.3'>
     <properties size='1'>
       <property name='download.size' value='836'/>
     </properties>
     <repositoryProperties size='1'>
       <property name='artifact.folder' value='true'/>
     </repositoryProperties>
   </artifact>
   <artifact classifier='org.eclipse.update.feature' id='org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration.ui' version='4.0.3'>
     <properties size='1'>
       <property name='download.size' value='940'/>
     </properties>
     <repositoryProperties size='1'>
       <property name='artifact.folder' value='true'/>
     </repositoryProperties>
   </artifact>
   <artifact classifier='org.eclipse.update.feature' id='org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration.server' version='4.0.1'>
     <properties size='1'>
       <property name='download.size' value='933'/>
     </properties>
     <repositoryProperties size='1'>
       <property name='artifact.folder' value='true'/>
     </repositoryProperties>
   </artifact>
   ```
5. Add the following to repository/components/configuration/org.eclipse.update/platform.xml

   ```
   <feature id="org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration.ui" url="features/org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration.ui_4.0.3/" version="4.0.3">
   </feature>
   <feature id="org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration.server" url="features/org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration.server_4.0.1/" version="4.0.1">
   </feature>
   <feature id="org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration" url="features/org.wso2.carbon.identity.self.registration_4.0.3/" version="4.0.3">
   </feature>
   ```
6. Add the following to repository/components/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info

   ```
   org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration,4.0.1,plugins/org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration_4.0.1.jar,4,true
   org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration.stub,4.0.0,plugins/org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration.stub_4.0.0.jar,4,true
   org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration.ui,4.0.3,plugins/org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration.ui_4.0.3.jar,4,true
   ```
7. Restart your service and verify that the Sign-up link shows back up on the start page and that you can create a new account.