# Disable WSO2 IS 5.0.0 Register Button

Tags: button, wso2, identity, wso2-identity-server

I want to disable the **register button** on the WSO2 dashboard. I only want administrators to provision user accounts.

I already saw this post on disabling the register feature: [wso2 identity server - user self registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429196/wso2-identity-server-user-self-registration) but the **Identity Self Registration** feature is not listed under installed features. Therefore I can not uninstall it.

Is it named something else in IS 5.0.0? Has anybody figured out a way to remove this feature either through the GUI or modifying the code?

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `Register` button, you can remove the following entry in `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/dashboard/landing.html` file.

```
<button id="register" class="btn btn-primary register">Register</button>
```

But this would not remove self registration admin service which can be accessed by  `https://localhost:9443/services/UserRegistrationAdminService?wsdl`  However,  if you are not exposing the  `/services/*` to outside the firewall that would not be an issue.   If not, you may need to remove the OSGI bundle that expose this service. OSGI bundle is `org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.registration_4.2.2.jar` But it seems that we can not remove from installed features as not listed.