# How to disable create account feature on wso2 admin portal

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I want to disable the create account feature on the WSO2 admin portal.
[image]

Come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28767665/disable-wso2-is-5-0-0-register-button) solution which says there is a way to hide the button by editing particular frontend view.
Is there any other workaround to disable that button and let only administrators to create user accounts without interfering frontend?
I mean can I get the desired result by editing some configuration files or some components in carbon portal?

Comment: If your ultimate goal is to prevent self signups,  you can follow https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/customizing-the-developer-portal/enabling-or-disabling-self-signup/#disabling-self-signup

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely disable the self-sign-up feature you can follow [1]. This will disable the feature for the tenant of the user who has logged into the carbon management console and disabled this feature. If you want to restrict this feature to particular users then you can add a self-sign-up workflow and accept/reject the self-sign-up request [2].

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/customizing-the-developer-portal/enabling-or-disabling-self-signup/#disabling-self-signup

[2] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/customize-product/customizations/adding-a-user-signup-workflow/

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your deployment.toml file, I found it more effective than the official documentation.

```
[identity_mgt.endpoint]
enable_self_signup_endpoint=false
```